# How to get values from a matrix to a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this array as an output of a json.loads and I need to get the title and the duration, but not videos, only tracklist:

```
`[{'styles': ['Latin', 'Ballad'],
  'genres': ['Latin', 'Pop'],
  'videos': [{'duration': 285,
    'embed': True,
    'title': 'Crazy',
    'description': '',
    'uri': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7QYo-9SlP0'},
   {'duration': 247,
    'embed': True,
    'title': 'Crazy2',
    'description': '',
    'uri': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BkYKwHLXiU'},
   {'duration': 226,
    'embed': True,
    'title': 'Crazy4',
    'description': '',
    'uri': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rf2jwgSXJVM'},
   {'duration': 189,
    'embed': True,
    'title': 'ricky martin - por arriba por abajo',
    'description': 'ricky martin - por arriba por abajo',
    'uri': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHiCWAtSjT8'}],
  'num_for_sale': 272,
  **'title': 'Vuelve',**
  'most_recent_release': 12264616,
  'main_release': 9625486,
  'main_release_url': 'https://api.discogs.com/releases/9625486',
  'year': 1998,
  'uri': 'https://www.discogs.com/Ricky-Martin-Vuelve/master/138279',
  'versions_url': 'https://api.discogs.com/masters/138279/versions',
  **'tracklist': [{'duration': '3:07',**
    'position': '1',
    'type_': 'track',
    'extraartists': [{'join': '',
      'name': 'Peter Wenger',
      'anv': 'Peter "Yussi" Wenger',
      'tracks': '',
      'role': 'Acoustic Guitar [Guitarras Acusticas]',
      'resource_url': 'https://api.discogs.com/artists/5484416',
      'id': 5484416},strong text`
```

How do I get all the title and duration to a dataframe?

Comment: post the expected result

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
test = {'styles': ['Latin', 'Ballad'], 'genres': ['Latin', 'Pop'], 'videos': [
    {'duration': 285, 'description': 'Crazy (Spanish Video Remastered)', 'embed': True,
     'uri': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7QYo-9SlP0', 'title': 'Crazy2 (Spanish Video Remastered)'},
    {'duration': 247, 'description': 'Crazy3', 'embed': True, 'uri': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BkYKwHLXiU',
     'title': 'Crazy4'}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(test["videos"])
df= df[["title", "duration"]]
```

At the end of this code `df` looks like this:

```
                               title  duration
0  Crazy2 (Spanish Video Remastered)       285
1                             Crazy4       247
```

Comment: Thank you but I got this error: ----> 8 df = pd.DataFrame(matriz["videos"])
      9 df= df[["title", "duration"]]
     10 df

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: did you copy and past this example or use your data?

Comment: I used part of my data because it is very long. I got this from json.loads

Comment: Your data is in a different format.  It appears to be a dictionary within a list, but I can't tell without all of it.  If you can access just the dictionary part like in the example, this code will work

Answer (score 0):

You can jo with pandas function `json_normalize` and then process the dataframe easier.

json_normalize "flats" the dict to a dataframe like this:

```
{
  "Name": Jhon,
  "Pet": {
    "Animal": dog
  }
}

# to 

Name     Pet_Animal
----------------------------------
Jhon       Dog
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html

Comment: Thanks, I have tried your solution and now I got this problem: KeyError: "Try running with errors='ignore' as key 'duration' is not always present"... It seems "duration" is empty in some songs, do you know how to avoid this error?